# Bjarne Stroustrup's P:PP Chapter 4 Drill

Tags: c++, vector, curly-braces

I've just started learning *C++* and I'm working by myself through *Bjarne Stroustup's P:P&P*.

I am on the *Chapter 4 drill*.

The problem I am having seems to lie within the order of the program. If I add another closing curly brace right before the vector to close the while-statement, I get the right output for `max_val` and `min_val`. However by adding that brace, the double named `sum` remains at zero even though I want sum to increment by the double named number.

If I compile the program as it is written now (without the addition of the extra curly braces), I get the wrong output for `min_val` and `max_val` but the proper output for sum.

Also, as you can see at the bottom of the program, the line:
`cout << " values were entered." << '\n'`; is not complete. I wanted to print out the number of total values entered but left it incomplete due to frustration and need of help. I am very new to programming and any constructive criticism, no matter how harsh, would be appreciated.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    double value = 0;
    double max_val = 0;
    double min_val = 0;
    string unit =" ";
    double sum = 0;

    cout << "Enter some numbers, followed by a unit of distance (m, cm, ft, inch):" << '\n';

    while (cin >> value >> unit){

        //determines entered value as max/min/both/neither
        if (min_val == 0 && value > max_val){                       // first number entered is both largest and smallest
            max_val = value;
            min_val = value;
            cout << value << " metres is both the smallest and largest so far" << '\n';
        }
        else if (value < min_val){// smallest number min_val = value;
            cout << min_val << " metres is the smallest so far." << '\n';
        }
        else if (value > max_val){// largest number max_val = value;
            cout << max_val << " metres is the largest so far." << '\n';
        }
        else { // number between smallest and largest
            cout << value << " metres is neither the smallest or largest." << '\n';    }

        //convert entered unit to metres
        if (unit == "m"){
           value = value;
        }
        else if (unit == "cm"){//converts cm to metres
           value = value/100;
        }
        else if (unit == "ft"){//converts ft to metres
           value = value/3.28084;
        }
        else if (unit == "inch"){//converts inch to metres
            value = value/39.3701;
        }
        else{
            cout << "I dont know the unit " << unit << ".";
    }
    vector <double> numbers; //reads input into vector
    double number = 0;
    while (cin >> number) numbers.push_back(number);

    for (double number: numbers) sum += number;

    cout << "The largest value entered was: " << max_val << "." << '\n';
    cout << "The smallest value entered was: " << min_val << "." << '\n';
    cout << "The sum of the numbers entered is: " << sum << "metres" <<'\n';
    cout << " values were entered." << '\n';

    keep_window_open("~");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've lumped two different assignments together (distance conversion + largest/smallest/sum).  What is the text of the actual assignment you're having trouble with?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Using sensible indentation would be a good start. Anyway, you can't just arbitrarily add and remove curly braces: either you currently have the correct number (regardless of their position) or you don't, so I don't believe you when you say that your program compiles but gives different output depending on whether or not you randomly inject "extra" closing braces.

Comment: Noted on the sensible indentation. Regardless of the addition of extra curly braces, how can I "organize this program" and what can I add to it so that it does what I want it to do? For example, Chad said that I lumped two different assignments together. How can I split that up? Really confused..

Comment: How does this even compile? You've closed main with a semi-colon instead of a curly brace.

Comment: When I compiled the program, it was closed with a curly brace. Bad copy and paste. I have edited since your post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small insight regarding the input loop, finding `min_value`, `max_value` and `sum`:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main(){
    // vector holding the input values
    vector<double> inputValues;
    // vector-input variable
    double temp = 0;                                    
    // variable holding the sum of the input 
    double sum = 0;                                     
    // variables holding the minimum and maximum input value
    double minVal = 100000; // note the initialization values
    double maxVal = -100000;

    vector<string>units;
    string unit;
    // prompt message; value input
    cout << "Enter the first value: ";
    while (cin >> temp >> unit) { 
        cout << "Enter the next value: ";
        inputValues.push_back(temp);
        units.push_back(unit); 
    }

    // conversion... 

    for (int i = 0; i < inputValues.size(); ++i){
        if (inputValues[i] > maxVal){ maxVal = inputValues[i]; }
        if (inputValues[i] < minVal){ minVal = inputValues[i]; }
        sum += inputValues[i];
    }

   // print result
   cout << "Minimum temperature = " << minVal << endl;
   cout << "Maximum temperature = " << maxVal << endl;
   cout << "Average temperature = " << sum/inputValues.size() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

For the conversion you can use a second container, e.g. vector to store the `unit`s and then create a loop using the same index for both values and units, with a `if`, `else if` block for each unit conversion:

```
vector<string> units;
for(int i = 0 ; i < inputValues.size(); ++i){
    if(units[i] == "cm") inputValue[i] = inputValue[i] / 100.;
    else if(units[i] == "...") inputValue[i] =...;
    // ...
}
```

### Note:

the input loop needs improvement, e.g. termination condition, think about termination keyword with `do`-`while` loop, handling of wrong input types, `cin.clear()`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference. Very helpful.

Comment: @Julian Anger Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)